# Specify line color in vistime/plotly timeline in R

Tags: r, plotly, vistime

I have a very simple timeline I've created using the vistime library in R:

```
library(vistime)
library(plotly)
data <- read.csv(text="event,group,start,end,color,line.color
                       RedBorder,Project,2016-12-22,2016-12-22,#e8a735,#FF0000
                       BlueBorder,Meetings,2012-03-15,2012-03-15,#e8a735,#0000ff
                       BlueBorder,Meetings,2017-01-12,2017-01-12,#e8a735,#0000ff
                       BlueBorder,Meetings,2019-09-12,2019-09-12,#e8a735,#0000ff
                       BlueBorder,Meetings,2018-08-15,2017-08-15,#e8a735,#0000ff
                       RedBorder,Meetings,2017-01-15,2017-01-15,#e8a735,#FF0000")

#Ordering the data, oldest to newest -- this sorts correctly
data <- data[order(data$start),]

p <- vistime(data)
pb <- plotly_build(p)

#The plot's dates are not ordered
pb$x$data[[2]]$x
#Attempting to order the plot's data.  These are the date elements. No luck ordering.
pb[order(pb$x$data[[2]]$x)] 
for (i in 1:length(pb$x$data)) {
  if (pb$x$data[[i]]$mode == "markers") pb$x$data[[i]]$marker$line$color<- data$line.color
}

pb
```

I'm trying to get the line color to match what is in the `line.color` column, but as you see, it's not assigning the correct line color to the points. For example, `RedBorder` should have red outlines, and `BlueBorder` events should have blue outlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was tricky! It seems you are getting burned by internal sorting of the data (based on time) inside the "built" Plotly object relative to your input data.

Basically, the `data$line.color` does not have the right sort order so the colors were not being mapped to the correct markers.

Simply pre-ordering your data based on Date e.g. `order(data$start)` fixes the problem. Moves `data` row 4 to position 3. EDIT: it appears that sort order may be more complicated, so use `match` to set the order of `data` after making `pb`

Final edit with more complex data:
I originally posted edits without your complete update. You need to know what index of `pb$x$data` contains your marker X-positions. In your first example it was index 2, in your new example it is index 4.

```r
library(vistime)
library(plotly)
data <- read.csv(text="event,group,start,end,color,line.color
                       RedBorder,Project,2016-12-22,2016-12-22,#e8a735,#FF0000
                       BlueBorder,Meetings,2012-03-15,2012-03-15,#e8a735,#0000ff
                       BlueBorder,Meetings,2017-01-12,2017-01-12,#e8a735,#0000ff
                       BlueBorder,Meetings,2019-09-12,2019-09-12,#e8a735,#0000ff
                       BlueBorder,Meetings,2018-08-15,2017-08-15,#e8a735,#0000ff
                       RedBorder,Meetings,2017-01-15,2017-01-15,#e8a735,#FF0000")


data <- as.data.frame(data)  
data$color <- rgb(1,1,1,0)

p <- vistime(data)
pb <- plotly_build(p)


for (i in 1:length(pb$x$data)) {
  if (pb$x$data[[i]]$mode == "markers") {
    data <- data[match(strftime(pb$x$data[[i]]$x, "%Y-%m-%d"), data$start),]
    pb$x$data[[i]]$marker$line$color<- data$line.color
  }
}
#> [1] 4
```

[image: updated example plot with more dates]

Comment: Thank you so much.  It's working in the example, but not my actual code which is a bit more complex.  I believe the start dates in the actual pb list  need to be sorted by date to get it to work.. how might I do that.  When  do: pb$x$data[order(pb$x$data$start),]  I get the error: Error in order(pb$x$data$start) : argument 1 is not a vector

Comment: The data in `pb` are already ordered by date, it is the input data frame (i.e. the object you pass to `vistime()`) that you need to sort, because you use it later to assign the colors outside of the `pb` object

Comment: Andrew - re-posting an example so you can see that it's still not working properly-

Comment: You may need to determine what the order is based on the `pb` object and then adjust your ordering of the colors you specify accordingly. If your data are more complex, it may be hard to replicate the internal sorting that is going on within `vistime()` however in principle you should be able to match

Comment: That's the thing.. I have absolutely no idea how the pb object is ordered!  It's very odd.  I posted a new example, using your logic, and you can see that it fails.  My data isn't any more complex than this example.. there's just more data points.  I can get the dataframe to sort, it's just that it's not corresponding to the date list in the pb object.

Comment: All I'm really trying to do is add a border that is not transparent, and have the fill be transparent.. you'd think it would be simpler...!

Comment: Try something like this. Yeah, I am pretty surprised. You cannot control the internal sorting of the `pb` object .. or the colors of the borders in an easy way that I could find in the documentation.
 
`match(data$start, strftime(pb$x$data[[2]]$x, "%Y-%m-%d"))`

Comment: Ok, so it turns out that the index of `pb$x$data` that you have to modify changes with the size/complexity of your dataset. So in your updated example you need to use `[[4]]` not `[[2]]` or, as I just updated in my example -- just do it in the for loop for the "markers" mode

Comment: hmm, thanks.  Ok, I realized that for some reason, my dates are being altered in the pb object and are 1 day off from the dates in my dataframe. So that could be causing issues.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I think I got it working, I had to do some date formatting but your solution seems to be on the right track.   Though, I did have to modify your code to get it to work w/ my example: data <- data[match(strftime(pb$x$data[[2]]$x, "%Y-%m-%d"), data$start),]